# Error trying to Connect to GMail with MailKit

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, mailkit, google-oauth-.net-client

I've got the following code...

```
var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets
{
    ClientId = "<< MY CLIENT ID>>",
    ClientSecret = "<<MY CLIENT SECRET>>"
},
                new[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly" },
                "<<EMAIL ADDRESS>>",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore("Mail2.Auth.Store")).Result;

using (var client = new ImapClient())
{
    // THE CODE FAILS ON THIS NEXT LINE
    client.Connect("imap.gmail.com", 993, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
    client.Authenticate("<<EMAIL ADDRESS>>", credential.Token.AccessToken);
}
```

When run, the code fails on the indicated like with `AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.`

I initially thought that is was 'cos the account had 2-step authentication on. So, I set up another account ensuring it just used the regular authentication settings and I got the same error.

I have found a number of posts, here and elsewhere, that deal with this exception but they seem to deal with the issue of working with the `SmtpClient()` and here, as you can see from the code, I'm getting the error with the `ImapClient()`.

Can anyone suggest what it is that may be the cause of the error? Is it GMail? MailKit? .NET? All of the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your system does not accept the GMail's SSL certificate.

You can override `client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback`.

A very simple example of a solution might look like this:

```
client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = () => true;
```

Obviously that means that if anyone ever spoofed imap.gmail.com, your software would get caught in a MITM attack, so that's not ideal.

You'll likely want to match the certificate's thumbprint against a known thumbprint or else add the certificate to your local certificate store and assign a trust level to it.

Comment: A more detailed implementation of the callback can is available on MimeKit's website. http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/P_MailKit_MailService_ServerCertificateValidationCallback.htm